# How to change resources' output directory in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui

I'm creating a Windows/Mac app with MAUI. The app has lots of images for buttons. When I build or publish the app all these images are created in exe's working directory by default (**app is unpackaged**). For images when I build the app, I want them to created in `APP_DIRECTORY\Resources\Images` and for the fonts in this directory `APP_DIRECTORY\Resources\Fonts`. Like in the solution explorer in VS. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want them to created in APP_DIRECTORY\Resources\Images and for the
> fonts in this directory APP_DIRECTORY\Resources\Fonts. Like in the
> solution explorer in VS

The `\Resources\Images` and `\Resources\Fonts` folder you see in the solution explorer in VS is used for the app's bundled file : such as the image and fonts resource when you build the project. These files can't be writen at runtime after you package the project.

In addtion, did you check the official document about the [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows)? You can put the file into the app's data directory or cache directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I'm using File system helpers for some caching and data. But I'm not trying to change any assets in runtime. When I build the app in VS, all assets are created in `bin\Debug\net7.0\win10` directory (same path with exe created after build). Also, same thing happens in release mode and when I started the app, if any of assets are not in this directory, they don't appear like expected. I just want to organize this directory by dividing it into folders if it's possible. Because there is tooo many assets and directory look like mess.

Comment: These files are app's bundle resource. You can't do that, if you change the path, the project can't find the files. In addition, maui packages the windows as msix. You can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11728).  @Erdogan

Comment: I see. Installation path is not a problem. I should get used to the mess. ) Thanks!